# How to install pyclewn in plain vim?

Tags: vim

I note that pyclewn can be installed in plain vim since version 7.3 due to it supports netbeans.
So I enabled netbeans_intg and autocmd features in my vim73.
 However, when I was trying to 
install it by:
`$sudo python setup.py install --force`
I get a return message of:
`"Failed to run 'gvim' as Vim."`
I am pretty sure I have set up the environment variable EDITOR as /usr/bin/vim.
Any idea?

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: what platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Given the output message "'gvim' as Vim". It is most likely that you set EDITOR incorrectly

```
> EDITOR=vim
> echo EDITOR
```

this should return 'vim'. Then,

```
> export EDITOR
> vimdir=$HOME/.vim python setup.py install --force --home=$HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try their local installation approach. This might work better for you. From their installation notes:

### Both binaries and runtime

Local installation of the pyclewn binaries and the runtime file is done with the command:

```
vimdir=$HOME/.vim python setup.py install --force --home=$HOME
```